# "Where do you stay?" vs "Where do you live?"

Tags: differences, american-english, phrase-usage, non-native-english

I am not a native speaker of English and I was having a casual conversation with my friends in the US. I asked them, "Where do you stay?" (which is pretty common in India, as far as I know) for which they gave me a surprised look and told me that people generally don't use the word "stay" and instead the same question will be asked as, "where do you live?".

If I use the word stay, is that offensive or is it just uncommon? What's the major difference between the two usages?

Comment: I think this is an excellent question. The use of "stay" in this context does occur quite often, and as a native speaker of US English, it always strikes me as mannered and pretentious, and I think you're right right to say that it is confusing. The editor in charge of NYT Cooking, who authors an email that I receive, constantly uses "stay" in place of "live" for no good reason that I can see. I have written to inquire why, and I'll let you know if I receive an answer. His use today: "The Thursday night plan, at least where I stay, is smoky tomato carbonara".

Comment: Where do you stay? in Indian English for Where do you live? In the west, stay is never live. It implies that the question is not about your permanent place of residence. Period.

Comment: As I understand it "stay" for "reside" is absolutely standard Scots dialect. I didn't know that it was common in India. I do wonder whether its use in India is a result of a large number of Scots having been recruited as soldiers by the East India company. Many of these men married Indian women and were the ancestors of the Anglo-Indian community. I understand, again, that the Anglo-Indians speak English as their mother tongue and I wouldn't be at all surprised to find that there were elements of Scots dialect in that English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just uncommon. Uncommon enough to be confusing, and so worth avoiding, unless you are operating in a dialect where it is normal.

The word would be "live" in US English, Canadian English and English English, but not Scottish English which also uses "stay" (which is why I said English English before).

Where "live" is used for long term residence, "stay" normally implies a short term visit. If you ask a visitor "where do you stay" they will probably give you the name of their hotel (while thinking you had made a grammatical mistake).

Comment: "Uncommon enough to be confusing.." - What causes the confusion here? Can it be interpreted in a different manner? Just curious. Yes, I'll definitely avoid that from now on.

Comment: Confusing as in they don't know what it means. They might guess, but they dont know, so they are confused.

Comment: I think DJ makes a very good point here and I would like to expand on it. This point is something that is continually overlooked on this site. What is technically not wrong can be confusing  and even in some cases misleading. Whilst to explain to non native speakers can be a nightmare. People who have a high points counts are not all native speakers and again sometimes the nuance of our posts can be lost on them. It is difficult enough between US, English, Scottish and Irish people sometimes. Oh! I forgot to included the differences between those lost individuals stranded below Watford Gap.

Comment: The confusion is because 'stay' normally refers to temporary accommodation. "I'm staying with my aunt for a week." "I'm staying at the Grand Hotel."

Comment: brad, _the_ Watford Gap, although there is a motorway (freeway, autoroute) service area called Watford Gap Services.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan If *stay* were used, the common phrase would be *Where **are** you **staying**?* And it (unlike *Where do you live?*) definitely wouldn't be taken synonymously with *Where is your "permanent place of residence"?*

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you, I'll better be careful in using the word stay from now on.

Comment: @Nagarajan Shanmuganathan, I think this is an excellent question. The use of "stay" in this context does occur quite often, and as a native speaker of US English, it always strikes me as mannered and pretentious, and I think you're right right to say that it is confusing. The editor in charge of NYT Cooking, who authors an email that I receive, constantly uses "stay" in place of "live" for no good reason that I can see. I have written to inquire why, and I'll let you know if I receive an answer. His use today: "The Thursday night plan, at least where I stay, is smoky tomato carbonara".

Comment: @IsabelArcher, as a matter of curiosity, why does it strike you as 'mannered and pretentious' rather than just plain wrong?

Comment: @jsw29, I wish I could answer that question, but I can't. I don't know why. I'll have to think about that. The editor is a native English speaker who is writing for the general public, so the choice has nothing to do with foreign usage. I've never heard a native English speaker use it in conversation. Come to think about it, I had never seen it in writing either. Yet I am not at all averse to new expressions when they make sense. But this one, as DJClayworth points out, does not. I can't tell you exactly why I think it sounds affected, but to me, it does.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey When it comes to separating the country into Daywn Sayth" and "Oop North" people, in my experience refer to "South of Watford Gap" and "North of Watford Gap" without the definite article and I've always taken the dividing line to be Watford Gap Services, not the geographical feature.

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker of Polynesian heritage, I definitely understand how the confusion arises, and I still choose to use the word “stay” instead of “live.”

In my case, the Samoan “nofo” is the catalyst for my choice, because “ola” or “live,” for me, means exactly that: “to exist.” So I am forcing a distinction into English conversation, which otherwise does not normally form amongst many native speakers. I will not alter my original approach simply because the concept is alien to my audience.

However, when someone is confused, I do rephrase: “Where do you reside?” It happens that the Latin root “residere” means “sit down, settle; remain behind, rest, linger; be left,” which are all the meanings for my Samoan “nofo.”

Comment: What a great language to speak! :)

Answer (score 0):

In America stay is used in primarily African American community. Caucasian people inevitably use live. Don't know why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).